# How to call API from the Identity Server startup

Tags: asp.net-mvc, oauth-2.0, jwt, asp.net-identity, identityserver4

I have a problem I hope someone could help to point me towards a solution. I have an IdentityServer 4 asp.net core implementation. This identity server is used to protect a WebAPI via various protocols such as Oauth2, WSFederation, SAML, etc.

**Problem**: some of the data I need to initialize Identity Server with (namely some parameters for each protocol) is found in the database behind the WebAPI. I need to make an *anonymous* rest call from the Identity Server project to my client to get this data and feed it into IdentityServer ConfigureServices call. But when I make the call, Identity Server is not yet started (obviously) and the call fails because it doesn't find the Identity Server endpoints. Without this data I cannot start Identity Server though.

I looked into two possibilities:

1. Some setting to allow me to hit the API endpoint without needing to go through the Identity Server middleware (couldn't figure out how yet)

-or-

2. Possibility to declare the authentication services later (after Identity Server starts with some basic config), but that doesn't seem to be an option either.

I would appreciate any pointers how you'd solve this.

Comment: why need IdSrv to perform *anonymous* rest call? shame on me, but can't catch

Comment: Just to keep it simple. The call can be authenticated, but the problem remains the same

Comment: Even if the call is unauthenticated, the pipeline will go through the ids endpoint. And that's not started.

Comment: hmm. looks, you missed the essential part of your question. what pipeline? client side? when you call a method with `[AllowAnonymous]`?? that's too strange